# How to get the value of an attribute inside an if statement?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="follow-me">
    <div class="author-follow"> 
    <a data-followed-by="author buyer" class="meta-badge">Follow</a>
    </div>
</div>

var $container          = $(this).closest('.follow-me');    
var followed_status     = $container.find('.author-follow a.meta-badge').attr('data-followed-by');
```

I tried using

```
if ($( "a[data-followed-by*='author']" ) ) {
    //do something ...
}
```

and tried

```
if (typeof(followed_status) == 'author' ) {
    //do something ...
}

if (typeof(followed_status) == 'buyer' ) {
    //do something else ...
}
```

But none of these solutions worked properly.

In console log for `followed_status`, I get the right class names (author, buyer)

Is there a better way?

Comment: what you want to achieve? `followed_status` will give you `author buyer` not `(author, buyer)`

Comment: _“Is there a better way?”_ - to do what exactly in the first place? You shown us some weird lines of code that barely make any sense, but you completely neglected to describe what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: I'm using ajax to update a count. But this count should only be updated within the right div. That's why I added an extra data attribute.

Comment: do you expect the attribute values to be separated for you? i.e. you want to get author or buyer, instead of "author buyer" ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: even if you use `$("a.meta-badge").data("followedBy")`, it will give you "author buyer".

Comment: How to know if that person who follow is an author or a buyer? you give us only a button with a `Follow` text, pls expand your question/code

Comment: Inside php I added an extra function to will display the status whether the follower is an author/buyer. I kept my code above simplified.

Comment: I'm planning to use `.split()` to turn `author buyer` into `author, buyer` and then use the array inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
if ( $(".meta-badge").attr('data-followed-by') === 'author' ) {
   //do something ...
   console.log('author');
} else if ( $(".meta-badge").attr('data-followed-by') === 'buyer' ) {
   //do something ...
   console.log('buyer')
} else if ( $(".meta-badge").attr('data-followed-by') === 'author buyer' ) {
   //do something ...
   console.log('author buyer')
} else{
   console.log('None')
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, if there is any `a` with the **attr** `data-followed-by` that contains **"buyer"** `alert('asd')`

```
if ( $("a").attr('data-followed-by').indexOf('buyer')>0 ) {
    //do something ...
    alert('asd')
}
```